# AVAudioPlayer table view and when press in table cell play desired sound

Tags: ios, uitableview

I make a table view and when press in table cell will be display detail view with a button for playing sound. How can I make a button play different sounds dependent on table view. Thanks!

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to check which row is selected in the tableView and then play the sound depending in which cell the user taps.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//use this to check for the row the user taps. [0 is the first row.]
//If you didn't use indexPath.row -> the function here will be for all the rows.
if indexPath.row == 0 {

     }


}
```

if you want to go into another view you can use the same method to perform segue.

the Segue Identifier can be change from the `Main.storyboard`

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "soundDetails", sender: self)
```

Also if you want to pass data into the next view to play the sound you can use this function

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let vc = segue.destination as! SoundDetailsViewController
    //vc.soundId is to access the data in the viewController and pass whatever value you want.
    vc.soundId = mySoundID 


}
```